Getting StackOverFlowException on GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream).CreateScoped()
I am trying to consume the HTTP V1 API to push notifications to my application. I am using .net 4.5 because it is a legacy application and the notification part has stopped working due to depreciation of FCM packages.
'''
var serviceAccountKeyFilePath = "C:\\edu-api\\SM.BL\\Auth.json";
        var firebaseUrl = $"https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/sm-parent/messages:send";
        var accessToken = "";
try
        {
            using (var stream = new FileStream(serviceAccountKeyFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                var credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream).CreateScoped("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging");
                Console.WriteLine(credential);
                accessToken = await credential.UnderlyingCredential.GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error in GetFirebaseAccessTokenAsync: {ex.Message}");
            throw;  // Re-throw the exception to help in debugging
        }

'''
I am trying to do it using the method above.
       var credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream).CreateScoped("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging");

This specific line is giving me StackOverFlowException. I have tried to put this part of code in a separate function and still this happens. What am I doing wrong ?
